# Invalidate Firestore client cache after remote changes

Tags: android, firebase, caching, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the Firebase Firestore client library with cache support in an Android Project with `.setPersistenceEnabled(true)`. Firebase synchronizes well and gets the data from the server if I'm modifying the Firestore database directly from Android code.

However, If I change the documents' data remotely via Cloud functions or using Firestore Admin SDK, the client doesn't get notified to invalidate the cache and retrieves the data from the cache even if it's outdated. I assume that Firebase has some logic inside which marks the documents if they are synchronized or not.

Does Firebase support to mark specific document as "outdated" which forces the clients to invalidate their cache automatically?

If it's not, I have to notify my clients to invalidate their caches manually via `.clearPersistence()`. I considered the following, yet not so convenient options:

- Sending a push notification with FCM
- Using a Firebase Remote Config parameter

Are there any other, more effective and convenient options to implement the same functionality?

Comment: Firestore automatically replaces its client record with updated server record if you have an internet connection.
If you use onEvent lister then its automatically change client-side record when anyone updates any filed in the same document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, If I change the documents' data remotely via Cloud functions or using Firestore Admin SDK, the client doesn't get notified to invalidate the cache and retrieves the data from the cache even if it's outdated.

It turned out that I fetched the data in a wrong way. I have a collection with multiple documents, and I queried the data like `.collection("users").get()` and serialized the documents by processing each `documentSnapshot` manually. That's why the clients got the cached, outdated data.

After I fetched the data by querying for the specific documents like `.collection("users").document("userId").get()`, clients invalidated the cache and retrieved the correct data from the network.